# How can I scale a bitmap and preserve it's neatness?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` function to scale down my bitmaps, so they come out with artifacts. Is there any trick or work around to smooth the edges?

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using this code.

```
bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, dstWidth, dstHeight, filter);
```

If the filter is true then it will get smoother edge.Otherwise the image will not be good

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the blury image problem by disabling scaling on bitmap load from resources:

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), path, options);
```

Also createScaledBitmap has a flag where you can set if the scaled image should be filtered or not. Setting the flag will improve bitmap quality.